# Installer failed on Windows 10 1703

Tags: windows-10, .net-4.5, installshield, .net-4.7

We have this installer(Installshield) successfully installed in previous build of Windows 10, but this time failed with 1073 which has build in .NET Framework of v4.7

The log indicated:

```
InstallShield 1:22:39: Setting external UI handler...
InstallShield 1:22:39: Ready to launch program block.
1: You must install the .NET Framework v4.5
```

and the following returned:

```
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=-3
```

The installer project has the following Installation requirements and all the containing binaries are build with .NET Framework v4.5:

```
1.Does your application require any specific operating system - No
2.Does your application require any software to be installed on the machine - No
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried recreating your response file? The ResultCode=-3 looks like an indication that the wizard didn't happen the way that the response file expected.

Comment: update Installshield to a version that [supports .net 4.7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110)#net_d). your version interprets the registry value incorrectly and thinks you have an older .net version installed.

Comment: 1073, 1703 or perhaps 1603?

Comment: Ah....  Windows 10 build 1703 Creators Update

Comment: @MichaelUrman FYI- I just hit a boot wim PE issue where a WPF app we have had for years won't run.  I think we are about to see some .NET 4.6 -> 4.7 appcompat issues.   Better watch out.

Comment: I donno if this is the answer. Probably will help for people who break their head like me. I came to know that 4.7.1 framework has Release number in registry as 461308 in Win 10 and 461310 in other OS. Coz of this it is not working while bundling with installshield.

Comment: What is your version of InstallShield ?